# Unable to get the "whole" childprocess output when using Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, python-2.x, popen

I'm trying to use a python script to automate an interactive console application.
(it's called BLEConsole and it's a microsoft store app https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bleconsole/9p5662fdq58v , not sure if that's important. )

So I've been using os.popenX and subprocess.popen to launch and interact with it, and it's working fine... mostly !

```
inp,outp = os.popen4('BLEConsole.exe')
inp.write('ls\n') # this one work
inp.write('open #01\n') # this one don't generate any output for some reason 
inp.write('format hex\n') # and it's working again ??
inp.write('quit\n')
print outp.read()
```

some commands work and print to stdout but some other don't.

they do work (the bluetooth device connects just fine) but i'm just unable to capture any output other than line breaks when executing this specific command. (yes it's supposed to output stuff, it does when I do it manually)

edit : yes I'm checking both `stdout` and `stderr`

Also I'm not able to capture the "BLE:" prompt using this method, I don't really need it but I don't understand why.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could it be outputting to `stderr`?

Comment: I don't think so, popen4 is supposed to merge stdout and stderr into the same pipe. I also tried using subprocess but nothing in stderr too.

Comment: After taking a look at the app source code I noticied that a check for Console.IsInputRedirected is the culprit...
Any way to circumvent that ?

Comment: The fact that `Console.IsOutputRedirected` is even being used (25 times in the main `program.cs` file) indicates the author(s) had some purpose or goal in mind when she coded it, although the reason for doing so is unclear (and undocumented). So I suggest you contact her (or them). Regardless, since it's open source, you should be able to change it as needed.

Comment: I wanted to save me that trouble and make quick script with python but it seems I don't have the choice D: